# Is there a way to determine the Superfetch cache hit rate?

Tags: windows, superfetch

I have several large analysis jobs in parallel that run over the same couple hundred gigabytes of data that are i/o bound.  When these run the Superfetch cache quickly consumes all available free memory, however I suspect the jobs are not synchronous enough in terms of data locality and the cache is just thrashing.

Is there a way to get any deeper information about exactly what the hit rates for the Superfetch cache are?